# Native Code: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, android-ndk, vtk

I'm trying to build native code on android because I want to use VTK for my android tablet. However, I am facing some issues when it comes to building one of the vtk examples. 
I know this problem has been covered here for an objective c issue but I guess it is different for me.

I get, from `ndk-build`:

```
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in /Users/lonnibesancon/Documents/workspace/TestNativecopy/AndroidManifest.xml    
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: ndk1 <= native.cxx
In file included from /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkTypedDataArray.h:34:0,
                 from /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkDataArrayTemplate.h:25,
                 from /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkIntArray.h:35,
                 from /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkCellTypes.h:39,
                 from /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkPolyData.h:60,
                 from /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkPolyDataAlgorithm.h:33,
                 from /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkConeSource.h:31,
                 from /Users/lonnibesancon/Documents/workspace/TestNativecopy/jni/native.cxx:25:
/Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkTypeTemplate.h: In static member function 'static const char* vtkTypeTemplate<ThisT, BaseT>::GetClassNameInternalCachedName()':
/Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkTypeTemplate.h:94:45: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
     static std::string thisType(typeid(ThisT).name());
                                             ^
make: *** [/Users/lonnibesancon/Documents/workspace/TestNativecopy/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ndk1/native.o] Error 1
```

Now I'm using MacOS Yosemite, ndk10e, vtk 6.3.

Here is my Application.mk:

```
# Build both ARMv5TE and ARMv7-A machine code.

APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a 
APP_STL := gnustl_static
# Set target Android API level to the application's minimum SDK version.

APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

Here is my android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
# VTK Libs
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkalglib-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkalglib-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkCommonColor-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkCommonColor-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkCommonComputationalGeometry-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkCommonComputationalGeometry-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkCommonCore-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkCommonCore-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkCommonMath-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkCommonMath-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkCommonMisc-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkCommonMisc-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkCommonSystem-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkCommonSystem-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkCommonTransforms-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkCommonTransforms-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkDICOMParser-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkDICOMParser-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkexpat-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkexpat-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkFiltersCore-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkFiltersCore-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkFiltersExtraction-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkFiltersExtraction-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkFiltersGeneral-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkFiltersGeneral-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkFiltersGeometry-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkFiltersGeometry-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkFiltersModeling-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkFiltersModeling-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkFiltersSources-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkFiltersSources-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkFiltersStatistics-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkFiltersStatistics-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkglew-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkglew-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkImagingCore-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkImagingCore-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkImagingFourier-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkImagingFourier-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkImagingHybrid-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkImagingHybrid-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkInfovisCore-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkInfovisCore-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkInteractionStyle-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkInteractionStyle-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkIOCore-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkIOCore-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkIOGeometry-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkIOGeometry-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkIOImage-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkIOImage-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkIOInfovis-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkIOInfovis-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkIOLegacy-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkIOLegacy-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkIOPLY-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkIOPLY-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkIOXML-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkIOXML-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkIOXMLParser-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkIOXMLParser-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkjpeg-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkjpeg-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkjsoncpp-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkjsoncpp-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtklibxml2-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtklibxml2-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkmetaio-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkmetaio-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkParallelCore-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkParallelCore-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkpng-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkpng-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkRenderingCore-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkRenderingCore-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtksys-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtksys-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtktiff-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtktiff-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvtkzlib-6.3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib/libvtkzlib-6.3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)


LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/alglib/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkexpat/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkglew/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkjpeg/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkjsoncpp/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtklibxml2/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkmetaio/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkpng/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtksys/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtktiff/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTK/build4/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/include/vtk-6.3/vtkzlib/

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures android_native_app_glue ndk_helper
GCC_ENABLE_CPP_RTTI := YES


LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndk1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.cxx

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `GCC_ENABLE_CPP_RTTI **:**= YES`?

Comment: Stupid me I forgot ":" but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: How do you compile your native code?

Comment: ndk-build in my jni directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable C++ in the NDK, add `LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti exceptions` and `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += --std=c++11` to the `jni/Android.mk` file. By default, the NDK supports only a C++-like language.

Note that there's no underscore between CPP and FLAGS. Also, I've used `+=` because this won't overwrite other flags such as `-Wall`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Now I have to correct the other errors I'm getting. Thanks a lot :). Would you happen to have ever tried vtk on android? If so I may have other questions for you ^^'

Comment: @LonniBesançon: Got my first Android NDK library working today, and that's with another developer writing the hosting application. Just tag the question, there are plenty of Android developers on SO.

Comment: Oh i see. Well I'm afraid since it's vtk related it might be too specific but I'll try and ask here anyway :)

Comment: How to do this if I am using cmake in Android Studio 2.2 ?

Comment: @YoloYolo: I don't know Android Studio 2.2, so I can't answer that. I also don't know if there's an existing answer already on the site, but otherwise feel free to post it as a new question.